# Python/Pandas - Setting y-value minimum as 0 when x-values are "range", not integers

Tags: python, pandas

So I'm creating a column graph and this is my code:

```
dataset = {'Year': ["1950-1955", "1955-1960", "1960-1965", "1965-1970", "1970-1975", "1975-1980", "1980-1985", "1985-1990","1990-1995", "1995-2000", "2000-2005", "2005-2010", "2010-2015", "2015-2020"],
         'Fertility Rate': ['7.45 ','7.45', '7.45' ,'7.45' ,'7.45', '7.45' ,'7.45', '7.469' ,'7.654', '7.182' ,'6.371' ,'5.255' ,'4.412' ,'3.713']}

df3 = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(dataset)
df4 = df3[["Year", "Fertility Rate"]]

plt.bar(df4['Year'], df4['Fertility Rate'])
plt.title('Brazil')
plt.xticks(df4['Year'], rotation=90)
plt.xlabel('Year Range')
plt.ylabel('Fertility Rate')
plt.ylim('0.0','10.0')
plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

Df2/Df1 and df were used to obtain this data from the CSV file, and I've just created a data set from it. I'm trying to do two things, ensure the y-values start from 0 and have a maximum of 10. This is the image:

[image]

If I remove the line "`plt.ylim('0.0','10.0')`", I get this:

[image]

I know that if I add in this to df4:

```
df4 = df3[["Year", "Fertility Rate"]].astype(int)
```

It would automatically set my y-value to be zero. However, since my x-values are not integers, they're "range", this doesn't work.

**Question: How can I set the y-value minimum to be 0 and also set a y-maximum value, when using x-values that are a "range" of dates, rather than integers?**

I couldn't find a similar question on the Python API.

Comment: I can't even copy and paste your code.  Fix something

Comment: Hi piR, I've deleted a line there and moved some stuff around. I'm not sure what else I can do if you're unable to copy it, sorry. I copied it directly from Spyder.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using strings in places where you shouldn't

```
# Notice I wrapped your Fertility Rates in an array and made it float
# This is sloppy, fix it up on your side
dataset = {'Year': ["1950-1955", "1955-1960", "1960-1965", "1965-1970", "1970-1975", "1975-1980", "1980-1985", "1985-1990","1990-1995", "1995-2000", "2000-2005", "2005-2010", "2010-2015", "2015-2020"],
         'Fertility Rate': np.array(['7.45 ','7.45', '7.45' ,'7.45' ,'7.45', '7.45' ,'7.45', '7.469' ,'7.654', '7.182' ,'6.371' ,'5.255' ,'4.412' ,'3.713'], float)}

df3 = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(dataset)
df4 = df3[["Year", "Fertility Rate"]]

df4.set_index('Year').plot.bar()

plt.xlabel('Year Range')
plt.ylabel('Fertility Rate')
# You had strings in the `ylim` definition.  They need to be numbers.
plt.ylim(0, 10)
plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: Hi piR, Thanks for that. I'm still very new to python, so the subtleties of arrays, strings, floats are stuff that go over my head. Thanks again.